# Find if 3G is enabled in iphone settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

is it possible to find whether 3G or Edge is **enabled in the phone setting** through applications?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to read the private Settings data (since apps generally can't access data that is not thier own), so I don't think this is possible. However, you can use the [Reachability]
(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code from Apple. Also, you can try going through `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: thnx.. but reachability only tell if there is possibility of data transfer through any of these.. but i just want to know if 3G is enabled in the setting because sometimes there might be some network problem due to which data transter is not possible but 3G is enabled in settings.